# addClass JQuery not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Javascript/Jquery noob and still figuring things out... but can anyone tell me why the following code would work in every browser and OS except IE8? Using the latest version on JQuery. (A snippet from a Wordpress site)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var current = <?php the_ID() ?>;
  var currentEl = $("#project-link-"+current).addClass('active');

  var prev = currentEl.prev();
  if(prev[0] != undefined){
    $("#prev-link").attr('href',$(prev[0]).attr('href'));
  }else{
    $("#prev-link").hide();
  }

  var next = currentEl.next();
  if(next[0] != undefined){
    $("#next-link").attr('href',$(next[0]).attr('href'));
  }else{
    $("#next-link").hide();
  }

  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    $(".project-image.active").removeClass('active');
    var num = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    changeImage(num); 
  });
```

Comment: Try using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` - I'm not 100% sure but old versions of IE made a clear distinction between element properties and element attributes. The `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions work just fine in IE8 however.

Comment: oldIE doesn't have a hashchange event, is that a plugin you are using?

Comment: Changing .prop() to .attr() seemed to do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestions

1. Check this line:

   ```
   var current = <?php the_ID() ?>;
   ```
2. `hashChange()` might not working in IE!
3. Consider replacing:

   ```
   if(prev[0] != undefined){
   ```

   With

   ```
   if(prev.length == 0){
   ```